# progress bar clarity to update every 5 seconds angular cli

Tags: angular, progress-bar, angular-cli, vmware-clarity, clarity

Hy, so I am trying to programm a progress bar to update every 5 seconds. I am using clarity and angular cli.

My html code looks like this:

Progress Bar

`<div class="progress demo">
   <progress max="100" value="0" data-displayval="0%"></progress>
</div>`

i used jquery until now, but for this project I need to use Angular and I basically have no idea how to make it work. I would be really thankful for your answers!

Comment: you can simply use setTimeout to call a function that incremets

Comment: Is the `data-displayval="0%"` actually represented by a value or is it literally just `+1%` every 5 seconds ?

Comment: Take a look at the demo app we use to test Clarity releases against. In the progress bar demo you might find some code that helps:

https://github.com/vmware/clarity/tree/master/src/ks-app/src/app/containers/progress

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this -

```
<div class="progress demo">
   <progress max="100" [value]="myFunc()" data-displayval="0%"></progress>
</div>
```

The function should return a number and inside the function you can handle the logic to make an update call every five seconds. Depending on what you are using this for, in Angular 6 you can listen to progress events ([url](https://angular.io/guide/http#listening-to-progress-events)).